Google Sheets: how to format currency with numbers right-aligned but +/- and $ left aligned and padded with spaces?
I've already looked at:

How to left align currency symbol but right align number?
How to left align dollar symbol but right align number?

The best number format I have so far is:
[$$]* #,##0
which results in:

I'm using a monospaced font, Chivo Mono.
Are either of these possible?

For positive numbers, prepending a blank space before the $ so that all the dollar signs line up in the column?
For positive numbers, prepending a + before the $ so that all the dollar signs line up in the column?


Use this custom number format:
_-"$"* #,##0;-"$"* #,##0

See Number format tokens.

This is beautiful! I'm surprised I haven't seen people use this format more often. Thanks so much for this format and for the helpful link to the docs.
